# Wild card characters in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

how to add a wildcard characters in hibernate?

I have try to do like this but already have a errors

"from Employee where epf like"+Epf+"%";

Epf is a int parameter pass to the query

Comment: do you escape the double quotes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You missing quotes `'...'`. The end-query should look like:

```
SELECT Employee WHERE epf LIKE 'text%'
```

so changing your code to

```
"from Employee where epf like '"+Epf+"%'";
```

should do the trick. **Note:** open and close single quotes `'`...`'` here `'"+Epf+"%'`

But you approach is not good. Adding text like this to a query is dangerous. Consider this for more information:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

It is much safer to use bind parameters:

```
session.createQuery("from Employee where epf like :epf")
       .setParameter("epf", epf + "%")
       .list();
```

Comment: Dear sir, user code work, thank you so much for your kindliness,  im using Hibernate code like this                             Session s=NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
         Transaction tx=s.beginTransaction();
              
      Query query=s.createQuery("from Employee where epf like '"+Epf+"%'");
        tx.commit();

Comment: Ok, so you use single quotes already? Could you please update the question? Please, add also the error message you get.

Comment: Nice it's Work, i used code like this
  Query query=s.createQuery("from Employee where epf like :epf");
              query.setParameter("epf",Epf+"%" );
  employeeList=query.list();

Comment: It's always better to use parameters, like `:name` or `?`

Comment: this is my error message "unexpected char: '%' [from lk.CEB.Entity.Employee where epf like 23%]"

but this is the way to use String parameter
.setParameter("epf", epf + "%")

how it is use with Interger Parameter?

Comment: how to use a wilecards in Int this is not works for Interger

.setParameter("mobileNo", mNo+ "%");

Comment: You can use `%` only with `LIKE` operator. Use can use `LIKE` operator only with Strings (varchar/char). With Hibernate HQL you can cast integer to string like this: `cast(epf as string) LIKE :epf` with `setParameter("epf",Epf+"%")`. Also consider using simple comparation (`<` and `>`) if possible.

Answer (score 3):

For Case-Insensitive %Like% Search

```
 Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Any.class);
 criteria.add(Restrictions.ilike(propertyName, value, MatchMode.END);
 criteria.list();
```

Comment: For a search based on value like 'john%' must be:
criteria.add(Restrictions.ilike(propertyName, value, MatchMode.START);

Answer (score 0):

You can use Like function of criteria builder for this.

```
        int EPF=7;
        CriteriaBuilder cb=session.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Object> cquery=cb.createQuery(Object.class);
        Root<Employee> root=cquery.from(Employee.class);
        cquery.select(root);
        Predicate predicate=cb.like(root.<String>get("epf"),"EPF"+"%");
        cquery.where(predicate);
        Query q=session.createQuery(cquery);
        System.out.println(q.list());
```